# Add single string of global configuration to custom Jenkins plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I followed the following tutorial to create a Jenkins plugin:
https://www.jenkins.io/doc/developer/tutorial/

This covered enough for me to create a useful plugin for internal use at work.  However, it makes no mention of what to do to add "global configuration" that would apply for all instances of your plugin in jobs.  In other words, I'd like to understand enough to add a single string of configuration data that would appear under "Manage Jenkins" > "Configure System" and apply to every instance of the plugin in jobs.

I am digging through open source plugins to try and figure it out now, but I thought it might be worth while to see if anyone has any pointers on here.

I will be sure to answer my own question with my findings if no one knows the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that mvn archetype actually supports generating a "Skeleton of a Jenkins plugin with a POM and an example piece of global configuration".

If you go through the tutorial a second time and on this page:

https://www.jenkins.io/doc/developer/tutorial/create/

Select 2 instead of 4 as indicated in the text, you will get a project that demonstrates global configuration.

I was basically able to copy over the SampleConfiguration class, the config.jelly and the help-label.html from the project generated with option 2 to my project generated with option 4.

To get access to the string, I created an instance of the SampleConfiguration class and used getLabel() in my class that extends Builder and implements SimpleBuildStep.

Also, here is a response from the jenkinsci-dev google group that says just about the same thing:

```
There's a project archetype for this called 'global-configuration', see https://github.com/jenkinsci/archetypes -- see the README how to create a project from this, or just steal from https://github.com/jenkinsci/archetypes/tree/master/global-configuration/src/main/resources/archetype-resources/src/main

All you need in addition is to look up the instance of your global config using ExtensionList#lookupSingleton from your build step (or whatever else you create), and retrieve the current configuration from it.
```

I didn't totally follow the bit about ExtensionList#lookupSingleton, but clearly there is another way to get at your global config aside from making an instance of the configuration class in your build step.